# Center divs on a parent

Tags: html, css

I have a problem centering floated elements on a parent div.
I need to center the divs inside the red background div.

You can see the source [here](http://achill.kabudos.es)

Comment: Will there always be only 3 pictures inside the larger red div? Or will the number of pictures vary? All pictures the same size? Surround all the pictures with a div, and center the div?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in another div that has

```
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
```